# Is it possible to synchronize Stack Rank (Backlog Priority) inside hierarchy in VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, kanban

[There are](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vj7DmdO4-Fg) many [presentations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16gOTI_OBw8) that talk about being able to synchronize work between the management and the implementation level in Visual Studio Team Services. That is, a manager can create a set of Epics of Features and the children of those (User Stories or Work Items) will reflect the goals of the project.

However, I could not find a way to re-order parent work items (Features) so that this re-ordering of their [Backlog Priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/stack-rank-backlog-position) gets updated in the backlog/board that contains children work items (User Stories).

So, my question is: Is it possible to [re-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776501/vsts-backlog-priority-altered-by-sorting-in-columns) Epics/Features in VSTS and get their children (User Stories) get automatically re-ordered as well?

The only progress that I have done is turning on "Show parents" in the User Story backlog and being able to re-order parent Features in the User Stories backlog. This does not affect the order of the User Stories in their backlog or on the [Kanban](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/kanban/kanban-basics) board.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not supported.

The priority or stack rank reorder only affects on the the Backlog/board of the specific work item type itself. That means you need to separately set the order of Epics/ Features/Stories.

So, if you want to do actions against the child work items based on their Parent order, then as a workaround just as you mentioned, you could "`Show parents`" in the **Parent** backlog and `Expand the level` (click the Plug + icon) to show them. See below screenshot for example.

However the requirement sounds make sense, actually there is a similar [User Voice submitted here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31016446-stack-rank-of-user-stories-should-reflect-the-orde) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future, VSTS team is listening your voice.

[image]

Comment: Dear Andy, thanks for the answer. Where can I find the 'below screenshot'?

Comment: @MaxWeedon Sorry for forgetting to attach the screenshot. See the updated answer.

Comment: The user voice you linked to no longer exists.