# Azure Boards - backlog items re-ordering themselves

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I inherited a project managed using Scrum in Azure Boards. Backlog hierarchy is set up as Epic > Feature > Product Backlog Item (PBI). Each Feature's set of PBIs were originally created in a specific order. Each time someone views the backlog and drills into any given Feature, the PBIs are shown in a different order than intended.

Is this just the way Azure Boards works? Are there rules to how the backlog is ordered? Is there any way to force an order on a Feature's child work items? I've gone as far as numbering each item in its title (1 Ingest into RAW, 2 Validate RAW data, 3 Document Source to target map, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not available way to force the order of work items.

Work items on **`Boards`** and **`Backlogs`** pages of **Azure Boards** normally will be reordered when users drag-drop a work item to a new location in the list. See the documentation "[**Organize your backlog**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/organize-backlog?view=azure-devops#change-the-parent-task-and-reorder-items)".

There also is not available permission option can restrict all users to drag-drop work items on Azure Boards.

[image]

---

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). This will make it more convenient for the engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

---

Comment: Thanks, Bright Ran-MSFT. This is the same conclusion I came to after further research.

Comment: I did one more search after accepting Bright's answer and found a way to change the ADO card reordering behavior. Bright's answer is still correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73368908/stack-rank-changed-automatically-for-many-work-items-in-azure-devops. This thread discusses changing the default behavior for card reordering as cards move across the board.